# Agent Based Coalition Bargaining Model on Python

Tags: python-3.x, social-networking, game-theory, mesa-abm

I am trying to run some simulation on Python for a social network in which agents play a coalition bargaining game. Which package is the most suitable for my needs? Are there examples that I could use when constructing my own code?

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for mesa](https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/intro_tutorial.html) is a good place to start. Also their GitHub has a solid number of [examples](https://github.com/projectmesa/mesa/tree/master/examples) that you can pull from. I have found that the developers of Mesa are super responsive to their GitHub issues as well (almost always responding within a matter of hours) so that has been helpful to me as I've found things that needed fixing in the tutorials.

I have also found it helpful to go off of some of the example models included in NetLogo when you install it (see https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/). It is not in Python of course, but it is helpful to see how they set it up and is relatively easy to implement their ideas in python with mesa.

In regards to which package would be most suitable, I think it would depend on how large of a simulation you are hoping to run. Mesa has been good for smaller/medium scale simulations, but if you are hoping to run something huge you may need to look elsewhere.